# Raise error when de-serialising json to an object with mismatched properties

Tags: c#, .net

C# code below:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

using static System.Console;
using System.Text.Json;

List<Person> source = new List<Person>();

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("data.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    source = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(json);

    foreach (Person person in source)
    {
        WriteLine(person.Id);
    }
    
}

public class Person
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And the json file:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Firstname": "Hello",
    "Lastname": "World",
    "City": "New York"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Firstname": "Foo",
    "Lastname": "Bar",
    "City": "Phoenix"
  }
]
```

I wish to raise and catch an error when there is mismatch between the properties of the person in the json file and the Person class in the C# code - is this possible?

Comment: With Json.NET you'd simply use `new JsonSerializerSettings { MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error }`

Comment: Relevant https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle any property that doesn't match with a corresponding one in your specified objects.

This is called JSON overflow (all other properties in the JSON will be stored in a Dictionary), and it works using the `JsonExtensionData` attribute.

Just declare another property in your object:

```cs
public class Person
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

This way, if you get a JSON with extra properties or properties with a typo in its name, like:

```json
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Firstname": "Hello",
    "lastNam": "World",
    "City": "New York",
    "Age": "32"
  }
```

You'll get your deserialized object within the `OtherProperties` dictionary, indexed by property name. In this case, you'll get two items in the dictionary: `Age` and `lastNam` with their respective values as JsonElements.

This way you could just check if there are elements in any objects dictionary, and throw an error. In your example and using linq:

```cs
if(source.Any(p => p.OtherData != null && p.OtherData.Any())) {
   throw new Exception("JSON contains invalid or unexpected properties");
}
```

More details in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: This is interesting, but I wish to actually throw an error when the properties do not match the class properties

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the post-deserialization option, to properly validate JSON by defining properties that must be there (required) and that must have a specific type and values, I recommend you using a JSON Schema to pre-validate the JSON input before deserializing it.

This way you can declare a schema like:

```json
{
   type: "array",
   minItems: 1,
   items: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
         Id: { type: "number" },
         Firstname: { type: "string" },
         Lastname: { type: "string" },
         City: { type: "string" }
      },
      required: [ "Id", "Firstname", "Lastname", "City" ],
      additionalProperties: false
   }
}
```

This schema above for example, defines that the JSON must be an array of objects with at least one item, and such items must have all four properties: `Id` of type number and `Fistname`, `Lastname`, and `City` of type string, with no additional properties.

Here is an article that talks about how to implement it in C#:
https://endjin.com/blog/2021/05/csharp-serialization-with-system-text-json-schema